# smallcaps style is not converting

Tags: node.js, pandoc

I am using pandoc to convert docx document to epub.  I am facing the following problem.

SMALLCAPS text is not converting to same format in epub.

Can any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give a minimal working example of your problem. Share the code and the rendering command. I would guess the problem is the font used in the epub does not support small caps, you will probably need to incorporate custom fonts.